# Wordpress pagination break on homepage

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I'm trying to get my homepage (home.php) to display a few posts thumbnails from a custom post type and to paginate through all of them.

Works OK for the first page, but when I try to get to the second page it doesn't work.

if I add the following code to my functions.php

```
function homepage_custom( $query ) 
{
    if ($query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query()) 
    {
        $query->set('post_type', array( 'custom' ));
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'homepage_custom' );
```

I get no posts.

Trying again without the check for the main query

```
function homepage_custom( $query ) 
{
    if ($query->is_home()) 
    {
        $query->set('post_type', array( 'custom' ));
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'homepage_custom' );
```

I get the first posts (i'm displaying 16 on each page). When I go to the 2nd page the URL displays "localhost/page/2" but I see the same 16 posts. Reseting the permalinks to default gives me the same results.

If I try querying directly from the home.php with this:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
query_posts(array("post_type" => "custom", "paged" => $paged));
```

I see the first 16 and I get 404 on the 2nd page. Again, reseting the permalinks gives the same result.

- I have 17 posts with this custom type.
- Displaying 16 each page I get 2 pages seeing the same posts, and displaying 5 each page I get 4 pages seeing the same posts.

  ```
   echo get_query_var( 'paged' );
  ```

This outputs 0 everytime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess I found it.

In the same page I have to show two different custom post types. One post type is dislpayed on the main area, 16 per page. And the other is used to fill a list in the sidebar.

Using this piece of code I change the main query

```
function homepage_custom( $query ) 
{
    if ($query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query()) 
    {
        $query->set('post_type', array( 'custom' ));
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'homepage_custom' );
```

but when I use the following in the home.php

```
get_side_bar();
```

The main query is somehow ignored, that's why I get nothing with the check for the main query. Without the main query check, I'm always searching for my custom post type and it works for the first 16 posts and then the query from the side bar somehow breaks it in a way it loses the reference on what posts to show and I end up with the same no matter the page.

Using wp_reset_query() method, removing this query from the sidebar.php or using WP_query instances where loops iterates through local variables solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code:

```
$pager_id = get_query_var('paged');
$postsPerPage = 5;

if($pager_id != 0) {
    $search_args = array( 'post_type' => 'custom', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'posts_per_page' => $postsPerPage, 'paged' => $pager_id);
} else {
    $search_args = array( 'post_type' => 'custom', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'posts_per_page' => $postsPerPage);
}

$results = new WP_Query( $search_args );
```

Comment: With your code the pagination arrows doesn't show anymore. If I try to access page 2 through the url ('localhost/page/2') still gives me a 404. Changing the name of the variable $results to $wp_query fixed this, but the pagination doesn't work either

Comment: If you use a simple pagination plugin: http://wordpress.org/plugins/tw-pagination/

You can then put this code after your loop:
`if(function_exists('tw_pagination')) tw_pagination($results, 'range=4&anchor=2&nextpage=Next&previouspage=Previous');`

Comment: that does fix the issue with the pagination arrows, but I can't see page 2 yet

Comment: Have you got a link to your site? I need more information.

Comment: i'm running this on localhost, i'll try to put it online. Is there any other info I can give you?